# Regular Expressions in Java: Matching a date value surrounded by other data

Tags: java, regex

I have a lot of files I am retrieving data from, and I have hit a wall with date values surrounded by other data. I am using Java, and the regular expression I am using works for the variable `string_i_currently_match` however I need it to match `example_string_i_need_to_match`

```
String example_string_i_need_to_match = "data 10/12/2010, data, data";
String string_i_currently_match = "10/12/2010,";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(

"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d(?:,)$"

);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileString);

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
System.out.printf("I found the text \"%s\" starting at " +
   "index %d and ending at index %d.\n",
    matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
found = true;
}
if(!found){
    System.out.println("No match found.");
}
```

Perhaps it's because I'm exhausted, but I can't get it to match. Any help, even pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I do not want to match `data, data` but just get the index of the date its self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` sign matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end. Removing those allows the pattern to match dates within the string.

Like this:

```
"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d(?:,)"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will match your date:

```
[\d]{2}/[\d]{2}/[\d]{4}
```

In what you posted, you made at least one error: Only matches a date at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}\\b");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Unless I am overlooking something this should match your date.

See it working here : http://ideone.com/HETGU